# Google Sheets API: proper GET construction

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to get the value of Sheet2's cell A2 in Google Sheet ID "ABC123" using a GET construction.

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/ABC123/values:batchGet?ranges=Sheet2!A2:A2&key=myverysecretkey123
```

gives me...

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I created the API key at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials but how do I connect Google Sheet ID "ABC123" with this API? (or is that even the next step?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's such thing as Authorization and Scopes when performing such requests. Try the [Javascript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) so you can see the AUTH flow including the use of scopes.

There's a snippet there where **GET** is used

```
function listMajors() {

        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
          range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
   . . .
```